# How to use superscript in axis labels with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

How to print angstrom square in x axis? I tried as follows.

```
labs(x = "x axis" (Å^2)", y = "y axis")
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

We can use `bquote`

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, mpg)) + 
       geom_point() +
       labs(x = bquote('x axis'~(Å^2)), y = "y axis") +
       #or
       #labs(x = bquote('x axis'~(ring(A)^2)), y = "y axis") 
       theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How to get the fonts in bold letters?

Comment: @sara just add `bold` like `bquote(bold('x axis'~(Å^2))` or `expression(bold(x~axis~ring(A)^2))`

Comment: @zyurnaiidi Thank you for your comment. square (superscript) doesn't come in bold letter.

Answer (score 32):

You should use expression, preferable combined with paste, as follow:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, mpg)) + geom_point() + labs(x = expression(paste("x axis ", ring(A)^2)), y = "y axis")
```

[image]

Comment: This is less finicky then the tidyverse solutions

Answer (score 4):

You could just simply use:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, mpg)) +  geom_point() +  labs(x = x~axis~ring(A)^2, y = "y axis")
```

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to use the ggtext package. It allows the use of markdown for labels, which I find easier to write and read.

```r
library(ggtext)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, mpg)) +
  labs(x = "x axis (Å^(2))", y = "y axis") +
  ## use markdown theme for simple superscripts
  theme(axis.title.x = element_markdown())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I just tried your code and it doesn't superscript the 2 for me. Has a version change broken this code?