# How to append superscript to variable to display in ggplot axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is similar question to this one [How to use superscript with ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37825558/how-to-use-superscript-with-ggplot2)

but instead of hard coded value of the label I have a string in variable and I need to append the "mm^3" to the string and display that in `ggplot`.

I have code like this:

```
genericPlot <- genericPlot + labs(y = wrap(ylab, wrap.length))

#' Wrap
#' 
#' @param x character, values to be wrapped
#' @param width numeric, max number of characters
#' 
#' @return Wrapped x
wrap <- function(x, width) {
  sapply(
    X = x, 
    FUN = function(x) paste(strwrap(x, width = width), collapse = "\n"))
}
```

I've tried to use this:

```
paste(ylab, bquote(~mm^3))
```

but this give me vector with 2 elements:

```
[1] "foo ~"    "foo mm^3"
```

Comment: Can you give a small reproducible example which demonstrates this appending?

Comment: I second @RomanLuštrik comment (and pint to `help('plotmath')` or/and [tidyverse's Plotmath page on github](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/wiki/Plotmath)).

Answer (score 6):

You were very close! Instead of using `paste` call your variable from `bquote` using `.(VAR)`.

```
library(ggplot2)
ylab <- "foo"
myX  <- "bar" 
ggplot() + 
    ylab(bquote(.(ylab) *" ~ "* mm^3)) +
    xlab(bquote(.(myX) *" ~ "* kg^2))
```

[image]

Comment: do you know how to make it work with wrap? if I call wrap before bquote I get `mm^3` aligned to top and big space and if I do wrap after bquote I've got `*` as label or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

I could not follow your case with the brief time available, but I have used the following code once to produce the output below

```
scale_y_continuous(trans="log10", breaks=ybreaks, name= expression(Discharge~~ or ~~ flow ~~ group("[",m^3/s, "]")))
```

[image]

Comment: what about if "Discharge" is a string in variable?

Comment: better to have a look to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973898/combining-paste-and-expression-functions-in-plot-labels