# Are there unicode characters for superscript C and Z?

Tags: r, ggplot2, unicode, superscript

I am interested in creating a label for `ggplot` that includes non-standard characters and glyphs. In particular, I am interested in printing `BETA^WAZ, BETA^DDC`, i.e. where the `BETA` is the Greek glyph and `WAZ` and `DDC` are superscript capitals. Based on the guide [here](https://rupertshepherd.info/resource_pages/superscript-letters-in-unicode) and other resources I have come up with the following:

`paste0("Corr(\u03B2", "\u1D42", "\u1D2C", "\u2C6B", ", ", "\u03B2", "\u1D30", "\u1D30", "\uA7FD", ")"))`

However, this is not the correct C character. In addition, there does not appear to exist a unicode superscript capital Z. Does anyone know of a resource that would have such a character?

EDIT: I may be mistaken but `bquote()` does not appear to provide what I'm looking for either; for example, see dummy code below, which does not produce the desired label:

```
data <- data.frame(x = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4),
y = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4))

plot <- ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_line() +
  xlab(paste0("Corr(", bquote(beta^WAZ), ", ", bquote(beta^DDC), ")"))
```

Comment: Are you sure you need to do this in Unicode characters? I don't know ggplot well, but you can do this with standard R plotting - `plot(0:1); text(1.5, 0.5, bquote(Beta^WAZ))`

Comment: The `bquote()` approach should work with ggplot2 too, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/37825558/12957340 - if you could please expand your example @Wilson King it might help with troubleshooting

Comment: @jared_mamrot I've edited now with an example. `bquote()` does not appear to work and produces a label Corr(^, ^)

Comment: I don't think you're doing the expression correctly. E.g. `xlab('Corr('~beta^WAZ~','~beta^DDC~')')` works okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer in the @thelatemail's comment above didn't render correctly on my system, so here is another potential solution using `bquote()`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
data <- data.frame(x = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4),
                   y = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4))

ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_line() +
  xlab(bquote("Corr(\u03B2" ^WAZ~", \u03B2" ^DDC~")"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>