# How to add a superscript within a parenthesis while also using another symbol to a ggplot y axis title?

Tags: r, ggplot2, symbols, axis-labels, yaxis

I am trying to add a superscript to my Y-axis title on ggplot but can't get it to work. I looked at similar questions on here such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37825558/how-to-use-superscript-with-ggplot2), but I think that because I have another symbol within the same parenthesis it is not working.

I need my Y-axis title label to be: Total Density (individuals ∙ L⁻¹)

I have tried the following:

1.

```
labs(y="Total Density (individuals ∙"~L^-1)
```

which almost works but I can't figure out how to add the closing parenthesis to this

2.

```
labs(y="Total Density"~(individuals ∙ L^-1))
```

gives an error

3.

```
labs(y="Total Density"~(individuals~L^-1))
```

this works, except when I try to add the multiplication ∙ symbol

4.

```
ylab("Total Density" "(individuals p "~L^-1*")")
```

this also gives an error

5.

```
ylab("Total Density" (~individuals ∙ L^-1))
```

gives an error

6.

```
labs(y=expression(Total~Density~(~individuals~∙~L^{-1})))
```

error

7.

```
labs(y=expression(Total~Density~(individuals ∙ L^-1)))
```

error

8.

```
ylab(bquote('Total Density (individuals ∙ L^-1)'))
```

not putting the "-1" as superscript

9.

```
ylab(bquote('Total Density (individuals ∙ L'^-1))
```

almost works but again, can't figure out how to add the closing parenthesis to this

I feel like I am close to get what I need, but no matter what I do I can't get it to work. Is there another way I should be typing in the multiplication sign to get this to work? I basically just copied/pasted "∙" to be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `bquote(Total~density~(Individuals%.%L^-1))`

```r
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(y = bquote(Total~density~(Individuals%.%L^-1)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know I could use the "%" for this.

Comment: @FishyFishies  Read `?plotmath`

Comment: @IRTFM wow this is great,  will definitely come in handy. thank you for sharing

Answer (score 2):

Works with `paste`

```
ggplot(economics, aes(date, unemploy)) + geom_line() + 
ylab(~paste("Total density (individuals ∙ ",L^-1,")"))
```

[image]

Comment: `paste` is a plotmath function with different arguments than base `paste`.  `paste0` may or may not work the same depending on what sort of evaluation mechanism is in place. Sometimes that’s difficult to predict in the tidyverse world.